# Display None values in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, nonetype

By default, IPython doesn't seem to display `None` values:

```
In [1]: x = 1

In [2]: x
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: y = None

In [4]: y
```

I often end up writing `y is None` to be sure. How can I configure IPython to always show the value, even if it is `None`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is deliberate, since *all* expressions return something, even if it is only `None`. You'd see nothing *but* `None` in your interpreter.

You can explicitly show the return value with `repr()` or `str()`, or by printing (which calls `str()` on results by default):

```
>>> y = None
>>> repr(y)
'None'
>>> str(y)
'None'
>>> print repr(y)
None
>>> print y
None
```

`print repr()` would be closest to what the interpreter does if an expression result is not `None`.

The regular Python interpreter uses [`sys.displayhook()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook) to display interpreter expression results; the IPython interpreter uses [it's own hook to do this](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13/api/generated/IPython.core.displayhook.html#displayhook), but this hook explicitly ignores `None`.

You can certainly use your own wrapper, the following hook delegates to a pre-existing hook and always displays `None`, regardless:

```
import sys

_chained_hook = sys.displayhook
def my_displayhook(res):
    _chained_hook(res)
    if res is None:
        sys.stdout.write('None\n')

sys.displayhook = my_displayhook
```

Comment: I'd be happy with assignments displaying as `None` (explicit vs implicit and all that jazz). Is it possible to make IPython do so?

Comment: I find the IPython API documentation to be rather dense and unhelpful; the `sys.displayhook()` function is normally called, which is what IPython hooks into with a [display trap](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.display_trap.html), presumabaly that provides hooks to change behaviour there.

Comment: Note that assignments are not expressions, they are statements, so they don't display anything anyway as there is no return value.

Comment: The link to the display trap is now broken.

Comment: @Bach: thanks, corrected by linking to the new location for the version I referred to at the time.

Answer (score 3):

Use `print`:

```
>>> y = None
>>> print y
None
```

Comment: This doesn't "configure IPython to always show the value", it just prints `None`, once.